# Creating a generic method that accepts list of any entity class and check difference using apache Diff

Tags: java, java-8, javers

I had earlier created a generic method for finding differences using Javers framework. Then I had to change it to Apache Diff.
The following code is a simplified version of the actual code.

```
 public static <E> List<AuditsResource> findDemographicsChanges(List<E> entityAudit) {
    List<AuditsResource> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < entityAudit.size() - 1; i++) {
        DiffResult diff = entityAudit.get(i).diff(entityAudit.get(i+1)); //Not working
        List<Diff<?>> d = diff.getDiffs();
        final Integer innerI = new Integer(i);
        results.addAll(d.stream()
                .map(j -> new AuditsResource(j)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

This design was working fine for Javers framework and I could get the diff as follows

```
Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
        Diff diff = javers.compare(inputArray.get(i), inputArray.get(i + 1));
```

Since the Apache Diff requires a the entity class to implement "Diffable" and override diff function as follows

```
@Override
public DiffResult diff(Entity obj) {
}
```

Hence I'am not able to call the diff() in the first piece of code

```
DiffResult diff = entityAudit.get(i).diff(entityAudit.get(i+1)); //Not working
```

As it requires me to write the generic function inside the entity that recieves the generic Object instead of the Entity object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you say "not working" what do you mean? You get compiler error? Unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function as

```
public static <E extends Diffable> List<AuditsResource> findDemographicsChanges(List<E> entityAudit)
```

Comment: I'am doing that. I just removed it to keep the Diffable part separate from my problem.